send http request from flutter to django localhost
i am using the following code to send http request to my django localhost site:
var url = Uri.http('127.0.0.1:8008', '/apis/login', 
                    {'q':'{http}',
                    'phone': userName, 'password': password});
var response = await get(url);
var myResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
print(myResponse);

but it raised this error:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: ClientException with SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 38598, uri=http://127.0.0.1:8008/apis/login?q=%7Bhttp%7D&phone=dslfkslf&password=rrrrrrrrrrrrrrC%3A%5CUsers%5Cgeors%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CPub%5CCache%5Clog%5Cpub_log.txt

E/flutter ( 4683): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:154:7)

I wrote a Flutter app for Android and when I enter the address in Chrome it works fine

If you are trying to access the api on your mobile device it will not work. you will have to enter the IP address of the your local machine and replace 127.0.0.1:8008 with ip-address:8008

If you using emulator, Use 10.0.2.2 to access your actual machine.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The local ip 127.0.0.1 works for current device means. Your app will be sending request your mobile/simulator not your server.
You need to host your server on your local IP address.
To get IP of your machine for Mac

ifconfig en0

T0 get IP of your machine for windows

ipconfig

Then you need to run your django project with following command

python manage.py runserver ADD_YOU_IP_HERE:8000

Then replace the IP in your flutter code to send request to Django server.
